# Changing plot marker for every element inside the plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot

I have a matrix that i am using scatter plot to visualize it of size 800x2. I am trying to change the marker type for every 100th element, for instance from 0 to 99 markers would be 'x' from 100 to 199 markers would be 'o' and so forth.

However i get the following error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar
> index

This is my actual code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import numpy as np
color=['b','r'] 
markers = ['x', 'o', '1', '.', '2', '>', 'D', 'v'] 
X_lda_colors=  [ color[i] for i in list(np.array(y)%8) ] 
X_lda_markers= [ markers[i] for i in list(np.array(y)%2) ] 
plt.xlabel('1-eigenvector')
plt.ylabel('2-eigenvector')

for i in range(X_lda.shape[0]):
    plt.scatter( 
        X_lda[i,0],    
        X_lda[i,1],    
        c=X_lda_colors[i],
        marker=X_lda_markers[i],    
        cmap='rainbow',   
        alpha=0.7,     
        edgecolors='w')
plt.show()
```

My goal is to basically use any sort of marker to differentiate between every 100th element inside my x_lda[i, 1] label that are clusters being plotted. This code used to work following this question: [Plotting different clusters markers for every class in scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886268/plotting-different-clusters-markers-for-every-class-in-scatter-plot).

But for my case, it gives me the error described above.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
X_lda = np.asarray([([1, 2], [1,5], [2, 3],[3, 5], [3, 4], [6, 9], [7, 9], [7, 8], [7, 10], [7, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16], [12, 14], [13, 15], [12, 14], [14, 14], [13, 4], [12, 5], [13, 4], [13, 3], [12, 6])]).reshape(21, 2)
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
plt.xlabel('LD1')
plt.ylabel('LD2')
plt.scatter(
    X_lda[:,0],
    X_lda[:,1],
    c=['red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green', 'green'],
    cmap='rainbow',
    alpha=0.7,
    edgecolors='w'
)
```

For this 21x2 array, i'd like for change the first 7 elements to 'x', next 7 elements to 'o', and the last 7 elements to '>' for instance.

Comment: Maybe `color[i] for i in list(np.array(y)%8)` should be `%2` as `color` only contains 2 elements?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something like this, exchanging row 5 and 6 in your code above:

```
X_lda_colors=  [ color[i%2]   for i in range(X_lda.shape[0])  ] 
X_lda_markers= [ markers[i%8] for i in range(X_lda.shape[0])  ]
```

However, you should not loop throughout all of your 800 points and create one plot each. A workaround would be something like this:

```
# plot each point in blue
plt.scatter(
    X_lda[:,0], X_lda[:,1]
    c = "b",
    ...
)

# plot again using every 100th element in red
plt.scatter(
    X_lda[::100,0], X_lda[::100,1]
    c = "r",
    ...
)
```

this will *overprint* each 100th element with a second dot in red. You end up having only two plot objects with 800 and 8 points respectively.

Comment: Well, all it did was add a single red X in for half of the points, which isnt optimal